# Interpolating Z values from XYZ point dataset to alternative XY coordinates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I have a dataset with X1,Y1,Z1 values (x coordinate, y coordinate, elevation -> the red dots in the image below). I also have another dataset with alternative X2,Y2 coordinates (-> the blue dots in the image below), but these data do not include elevations Z2.

How can I interpolate Z1 values to X2,Y2 coordinates, for example with IDW interpolation in QGIS?

I would like them to remain as point coordinates and not transform them to a raster format.

[image]

Comment: Rather than estimate a point's value based on an adjacent point, you probably want to consider downloading a DEM for your area. Then you can use the 'Point Sampling' tool in QGIS or similar in Arcmap.